# When is $H^m=\{ h^m \mid h\in H\}$ a subgroup $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $H$ be a group and $H^m=\{ h^m \mid h\in H\}$.

I know that this is  a subgroup of $H$ when $H$ is abelian.
But I want to know that what happens if $H$ is not abelian.
For which $n$, $H^n$ is a subgroup of $H$ and for which $n$ it is not?

I tried for the nonabelian group $S_3$ and found that $S_3^{2k}$ is a subgroup of $S_3$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $S_3^{2k+1}$ is not a subgroup of $S_3$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

But I don't know whether it is true for arbitrary groups or not and I want to prove it if it is correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What should be true for an arbitrary group?

Comment: @JCAA For arbitrary groups, $H^{2k+1}$ is definitely not a subgroup of $H$. But I want to know that whether $H^{2k}$ is a subgroup of $H$ for arbitrary group $H$ or not. I know that this is true for $S_3$

Comment: For every finite group, there is at least one such m always( m = |H|). So it's integral multiples are. Hence, in this case, we will always get infinite such m.

Comment: @sushantkala: That is not true, take $H=C_3$, $n=3$.

Comment: About $H^{2k}$ take $H=A_5$, $k=1$ ($n=2$). That is not a subgroup because if it was a subgroup it would be normal and proper and $A_5$ is simple.

Comment: @JCAA thanks for correcting...I was thinking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want a counter example for all $H^{2k}$, not only for $H^2$. In fact I want to show that for any $k∈Z$ that $H^{2k}$ may not be a subgroup of $H$ (If it is correct and if not, for which $n′s$ this is correct?)

Answer (score 3):

For any finite simple group of even order, the squares are not a subgroup.

To see this, note the following:

Lemma:  If the squares from a group $H$ are contained in a subgroup $G$ then $G$ is normal.

Pf:  Let $h,g$ be arbitrary elements of $H,G$ respectively.  We want to show that $hgh^{-1}\in G$.  But $$hgh^{-1}=h^2h^{-1}gh^{-1}gg^{-1}=h^2\left(h^{-1}g\right)^2g^{-1}\in G$$ and we are done.

Thus, $A_5$ in particular is a counterexample

Remark:  For completeness we should note that the squares can't be the entire group.  As the group has even order (by assumption) there is an element of order $2$, hence the squaring map is not injective.  As we are speaking of finite groups here, it follows that the squaring map is not surjective, and we are done.

Comment: You "forgot" to prove that the subgroup $H^2$ (if it is a subgroup) is proper.

Comment: @JCAA  Ah, I thought that was clear (as the squaring map can't be injective).  I'll add a note to that effect.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your answer, but I want a counter example for all $H^{2k}$ not only for $H^{2}$. In fact I want to show that  for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ that $H^{2k}$ may not be a subgroup of $H$ (If it is correct and if not, for which $n's$ this is correct?)

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly true that for every finite group  $H$ there exists $N$ such that whether or not $H^n$ is a subgroup depends only on $n\mod N$ and contain all multiples of $N$. For this $N$ you can take, for example, $|H|$. That is because if $m\equiv n\mod N$, then $H^m=H^n$, and $H^N=\{1\}$.

For infinite groups the set of $n$'s  for which $H^n$ is a subgroup may be empty (say, the free group of rank $\ge 2$).